# Is there a wide character version of stat() (from sys/stat.h)?

Tags: c, file

I have been using stat() for checking the existence of a file, which I understand is better practice than trying to open a file.
However, stat() doesn't work for filenames containing unicode characters in other languages. Is there a wide character version of stat(), or something equivalent that I can use?

If not, what is the next acceptable solution for checking existence of a file?

Comment: You mentioned in response to an answer that for some reason was deleted, but you should mention in your question that you're specifically asking about a Windows NT-based environment.

Answer (score 6):

in windows   you can use the wide char version : [_wstat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff%28VS.71%29.aspx)